# Let the random point (X,Y) be uniformly distributed on the square

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable

Let the random point $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed on the square 
$D=\{(x,y):-1\leq x\leq 1,\ -1\leq y \leq 1\}$.
Find the distribution function and the probability distribution function of $Z=X +Y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *any* random variables $X$ and $Y$ (not necessarily restricted to the unit square, and not necessarily independent) with joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, and any real number $z$
we have that
$$P\{X + Y \leq z\} = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y = -\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
which integral can be easily set up by beginning students if they would
only bother to sketch the $x$-$y$ plane, draw on it the line $z = x+y$,
and think a bit about which of the two regions (above the line or below
the line) corresponds to the event $\{X+Y\leq z\}$.  Thus with $Z$
denoting $X+Y$, we can express the cumulative probability distribution
function (CDF) of $Z$ as

$$F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\} = P\{X + Y \leq z\} 
= \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y = -\infty}^{z-x}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
and so we can find the density function $f_Z(z)$ by differentiating
the CDF thus obtained. Those familiar with Leibniz's rule for
differentiating under the integral sign will be able to bypass this 
two-step process and write
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,\mathrm dx$$
directly. Note the lack of a proportionality sign as in
NeilG's answer: this is an equality.

For the special case of $(X,Y)$ taking on values in a square
region as in the OP's problem, the computation of $F_Z(z)$
becomes an integration of the joint density over a right 
triangular region or a pentagonal region that is the complement of a
right triangular region. For the even more special case of a uniform
density, even formal integration can be avoided since simple mensuration
formulas suffice. This latter is the geometric approach mentioned
by cardinal in his comments on NeilG's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Maybe Macro is right and the Wikipedia entry could be a little clearer.  Let's work through a bit of the problem together.  We see that in the (axis-aligned) square, knowing $X$ tells you nothing about $Y$ (and vice versa).  That is, they are independent.  So, you are looking for the sum of independent variables.  This is called a convolution.

So, let's try to figure out how a convolution should work.  We know that if $Z=0.2$, then one possibility is $X=-0.3, Y=0.5$; another is $X=0.1, Y=0.1$, and so on.  So, it might a bit of a leap here, to see that the density of $Z$ is:

$$f_Z(z) \propto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$

In other words, the density of $Z$ at $z$ is proportional to to the density of $X$ at $x$ times the density of $Y$ at $y$ where $y$ is the number that would have to be added to $x$ to get $z$: $z-x$.

We said proportional to because we still need the density of $Z$ to sum to one.

To complete the problem, try to simplify this integral.  What is the density of $X$?

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: @Macro: With homework questions, the accepted practice is to give hints, and not full answers.  The wikipedia entry describes the procedure as well, and even has a nice diagram of this problem.

Comment: Also, normally, I reserve downvotes for answers that are wrong, or misleading.  If you feel that more of a hint would be beneficial to the asker's education, my personal inclination would be to add your own answer.

Comment: Neil's answer misses the main point: justify that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Indeed, no (explicit) convolution or appeal to independence is necessary, though the latter is trivial. This can be done completely geometrically, if one prefers that approach.

Comment: @NeilG, I know the common practice is to point in the right direction, not answer the whole question, for homework. But, I think "Hint: convolution." falls more under the category of comment than answer. My intention wasn't to be obnoxious or ruffle any feathers. (+1, btw)

Comment: @Stéphane Why is any reference to independence needed at all?  It's not necessary to invoke independence in order to compute the distribution of $X+Y$--for that, you only need to know the distribution function for the bivariate uniform distribution on this square.  Neil, this consideration suggests that your discussion of independence may be more of a distraction than a useful hint.

Comment: @whuber Yes but I followed Neil's idea: he proposed to use the well-known convolution to derive the density of the sum of two independent r.v.; following this way, it is most interesting to focus on the independence rather than showing how to apply a formula

Comment: @cardinal: good point.